# Angular 6 scrolling event

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cdk

I have scrolling event implemented on my component using angular's cdkScrollable.

My code looks like below

```
export class HomeComponent {
    public hide = true;

    constructor(public scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher) {
        this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe((cdk: CdkScrollable) => {
            offset = cdk.getElementRef().nativeElement.scrollTop || 0;

            if (offset > 50) {
                this.hide = false;
            } else {
                this.hide = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And my `home.component.html` has the following code

```
<p>{{hide}}</p>
```

the problem is that the value of hide does not change even if scrolled past 64 but in console.log it changes.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I'm having the same problem and the zone suggestions are not working.

Answer (score 1):

the ScrollDispatcher in not running in the angular update cycle. You need to run your changes in a NgZone

```
this.zone.run(_ => {
  this.hide= false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
1. Import NgZone:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
```

2. Create a private access to NgZone in the constructor, and update your values using NgZone:

   `constructor(private scroll: ScrollDispatcher, private zone: NgZone) {
   this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe((cdk: CdkScrollable) => {
   this.zone.run(() => {
              // Your update here!
          });
       })
       }`
   For more info read this article: https://sumodh.com/2018/03/31/how-to-force-update-a-variable-in-angular-4-angular-5/

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `ChangeDetectorRef` from the `@angular/core` to trigger the change detection manually.

```js
export class HomeComponent {
    public hide = true;

    constructor(
        public scrollDispatcher: ScrollDispatcher,
        private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef
    ) {
        this.scrollDispatcher.scrolled().subscribe((cdk: CdkScrollable) => {
            offset = cdk.getElementRef().nativeElement.scrollTop || 0;

            if (offset > 50) {
                this.hide = false;
                this.cdr.detectChanges();
            } else {
                this.hide = true;
                this.cdr.detectChanges();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: On a strict type application I had to explicitly cast the cdk as in `this.scrollY = (cdk as CdkScrollable).getElementRef().nativeElement.scrollTop || 0;`